# Webshopapps matrix rate - How to check if UK postcode

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

I am using the free matrixrate extension by Webshopapps and after many years we found out an issue. Goods are only shipped to UK. My csv is setup with the country as GBR. Recently a customer entered an only numerical postcode and still managed to get an estimate for the shipping. How do I setup the file so that it can only accept UK postcodes? I tried to enter for each line all UK postcodes separated by comma, but does not accept it. Any pointer?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do a Postcode "Range" so from A to * which should hopefully stop any Postcodes people enter starting with numbers getting through:

[image]

Comment: Yes but this will only work with postcodes starting with A. I will have to enter all valid UK postcodes (which are 40+) and duplicate all weight vs price ranges for each postcode :( This will result in a mile-long file.

Comment: Ah I was under the impression it started at A and finished at Z when you put the Zip To as *. Did you try this just to make 100% sure?

Comment: yes I did try just in case but no luck. I think that the paid version allows to enter all allowed UK postcode in one cell separated by comma but the free one does. My app has been heavily customised and I am worried that if I upgrade it might break the whole website so was looking for alternatives.

Comment: Anyone help me, Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps matrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate.

Comment: @zus Sorry I am not sure how you would do this in grams, you may want to start a new question.

Comment: Anyone knows how to give free shipping using Webshopapps  Matrix Rates in SHopping Cart Pricing rule?

Comment: @KiwisTasteGood, can you please help me how to insert an individual record programmatically instead of importing from CSV